# Me’am Lo’ez online in English or Hebrew

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, jewish-books, translation

Is there a translation of Rabbi Culi’s *Me’am Lo’ez* available online or as an ebook in either English or Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

Otzar HaChochma has digitized scans for every volume of Yalkut Meam Loez (the Hebrew translation of the Ladino commentary for the Torah, in addition to modern Hebrew commentaries written by R. Shemuel Yerushalmi for Nach under the same name). Since Covid, the site has lifted their subscription and the books are free to read.

[Here is the scan](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/105203/p/3/t/10.50.7472405503122721/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c) for the first volume of the Meam Loez in Hebrew, the rest are easily searchable on the site.

Comment: Is the subscription requirement still lifted? I thought that was just a temporary measure

Comment: The first 150 pages are free